# SharePoint list to process XML data from email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a custom built PDF form that users can click send email. It will send an XML version of the PDF to me. I would like for that data to go directly to a SharePoint Calendar List that can be rendered into a calendar view.

What is the best method to achieve this? I do have Nintex installed and I have little SharePoint 2010 experience and no access to Central Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to send the XML to a document library and have an on item creation work flow start up. Using Nintex's Query XML action, you could pull out the bits of information you need into variables, and then create an item in a calendar based on that data.

Comment: Would I email enable the list? I'm trying to automate it without my intervention.